# Como pegar o valor guardado numa coluna, usando Cursor?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, cursor

Tenho um cursor que recebe todos os dados da minha tabela depois uso o Simplescursoradapter para colocar em uma listview.

Queria saber se com esse mesmo cursor eu poderia pegar um dado de uma *row* e colocar em uma textview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por cada tipo de dado que uma coluna da tabela guarde a implementação da interface [Cursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) disponibiliza um método para obter o seu valor.

Para obter o valor guardado numa coluna do tipo string deve usar o método [getString(int column)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString(int)).

Esses métodos usam um inteiro(índice) para identificar a coluna.

É possível obter esse índice através do nome da coluna usando o método [getColumnIndexOrThrow(String columnName)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndexOrThrow(java.lang.String)).

Assim, para obter o valor guardado numa coluna do tipo string de nome XXX deverá usar:

```
String valor = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("XXX"));
```